# How to arrange the buttons vertically in RibbonControlGroup (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, ribboncontrolslibrary

I have RibbonControlGroup with a few buttons.

```
<r:RibbonControlGroup>
    <r:RibbonToggleButton Label="button1"/>
    <r:RibbonToggleButton Label="button2"/>
</r:RibbonControlGroup>
```

On Ribbon buttons are arranged horizontally. Like (button1|button2). 
How to arrange the buttons vertically?

Comment: I think you should look at mentioned link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212272/Ribbon-with-Cplusplus-Part-Layout-Controls-in-Wi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, that I'm late to party, but may be this will help someone.
Since the `RibbonControlGroup` is an `ItemsControl`, the right way to go is to replace `ItemsPanel` like this:

```
<r:RibbonControlGroup>
    <r:RibbonControlGroup.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </r:RibbonControlGroup.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- Group items are listed below: -->
    <r:RibbonToggleButton Label="button1"/>
    <r:RibbonToggleButton Label="button2"/>
</r:RibbonControlGroup>
```

This approach conceptually differs from @Sajeetharan's answer, because he creates a group with a single child - `StackPanel`, while my sample still is an equivalent of the code, posted in the question: here's a group with two children of type `RibbonToggleButton`.

The difference will be meaningful with data binding scenarios, when items of group be populated dynamically through data binding expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use **StackPanel** and change the orientation to **Vertical** ,

```
 <r:RibbonControlGroup>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <r:RibbonToggleButton Label="button1"/>
            <r:RibbonToggleButton Label="button2"/>
            </StackPanel>
 </r:RibbonControlGroup>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I the beginner in WPF.

Comment: I want to combine buttons in ControlGroup, which located in RibbonGroup.

Comment: @Vlad Did you check the modified answer? I think this what you required. Please mark it as an answer if helped you

Comment: @Sajeetharan: while this was accepted, this isn't a right way to go. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep these controls in a container and set its Orientation property to "Vertical"
For e.g. using StackPanel as a container

will place the buttons vertically